# Opencv DNN set different Input on YoloV3

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm using the common implementation from YoloV3 to do some inference. Which works fine using the regular in- and output.

```
modelWeightPath = r"./yolov3.weights"
modelPath = r"./yolov3.cfg"
network = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelPath,modelWeightPath)
```

Since we are using some edge devices which often cannot "convert" the last few layers, I m about to use the original implementation to do only the inference on the last few layers.

I know how the layers are named (`network.getLayerNames()`) and I know how de data from the previous layer looks like since I saved them to do the testing. (see input data -> inputScale1 from conv_81 Layer)

```
inputLayers = ['permute_82','permute_94','permute_106']
inputData = [cv2.UMat(inputScale1),cv2.UMat(inputScale2),cv2.UMat(inputScale3)]
```

Now I m not sure how I should use that knowledge to do the inference since I only get exceptions from all my attempts.

```
network.setInput(blob=inputData[0],name=inputLayers[0]) - throws
outs = network.forward(outputlayers[0])
```

throws the following exception :`OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:2929: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) Requested blob "permute_82" not found in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181221::Net::setInput'`

```
network.setInputsNames(inputLayers)
network.setInput(inputData[0],name=inputLayers[0])
network.setInput(inputData[1],name=inputLayers[1])
network.setInput(inputData[2],name=inputLayers[2])
outs = network.forward() -> throws
```

Will throw: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:686: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181221::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes'`

EDIT:
But the thing is, that this example works:

```
imgPath = r'./frame_93.png'
image = cv2.imread(imgPath);
blobInputimage = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image,1.0 / 255.0,(416,416),(0, 0, 0))
network.setInputsNames(['conv_0'])
network.setInput(blobInputimage,name='conv_0')
output = network.forward('conv_81')
```

but still you cannot do the forwarding only from the permute layer to the yolo layer.

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of implications are used for "input layers". Do I understand you right, that currently you are trying to tell opencv that some intermediate layer should be used as an input layer, even though there are connections to that layer from earlier layers?

Comment: Hello @Micka, yes exactly, thats what I m trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

So far I was able to get the same result as if I would to it by inferencing the regular network. Therefore I created per scale a "new" network from the .cfg file by removing all entries except the yolo entrie, as example yolov3_scale_1.cfg looks like:

```
[net]
# Testing
# batch=1
# subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=255
height=13
channels=13
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=80
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

The code verify the output looks like:

```
def getOutputLayerNames(network):
    layer_names = network.getLayerNames() 
    outputlayers=[layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    return outputlayers

# Load Network
modelWeightPath = r".\yolov3.weights"
modelPath_scale_1 = r".\yolov3_scale_1.cfg"
network_scale_1 = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelPath_scale_1,modelWeightPath)

modelPath_scale_2 = r".\yolov3_scale_2.cfg"
network_scale_2 = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelPath_scale_2,modelWeightPath)

modelPath_scale_3 = r".\yolov3_scale_3.cfg"
network_scale_3 = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelPath_scale_3,modelWeightPath)

networks = [network_scale_1,network_scale_2,network_scale_3]

outputLayers1 = getOutputLayerNames(network_scale_1)
outputLayers2 = getOutputLayerNames(network_scale_2)
outputLayers3 = getOutputLayerNames(network_scale_3)



## Read FileStorage - Network input
pathToFile = r'.\previousLayerOutput.yml'
s = cv2.FileStorage()
s.open(pathToFile, cv2.FileStorage_READ)

# Get outputs to verify behaviour
inputScale1 = s.getNode('conv_81').mat()
inputScale2 = s.getNode('conv_93').mat()
inputScale3 = s.getNode('conv_105').mat()

ouputOfYoloScale1 = s.getNode('yolo_82').mat()
ouputOfYoloScale2 = s.getNode('yolo_94').mat()
ouputOfYoloScale3 = s.getNode('yolo_106').mat()

correctOutputs = [ouputOfYoloScale1,ouputOfYoloScale2,ouputOfYoloScale3]

inputs = [inputScale1,inputScale2,inputScale3]
outputs = []
for network_with_different_scales,imageInputScaled in zip(networks,inputs):
    network_with_different_scales.setInputsNames('permute_0')
    network_with_different_scales.setInput(imageInputScaled)
    outputs.append(network_with_different_scales.forward('yolo_0'))

strides = [32,16,8] # need to do it manually
for outputIdx,stride in zip(range(0,len(outputs)),strides):
    outputs[outputIdx][:,3] = outputs[outputIdx][:,3]/stride
    outputs[outputIdx][:,2] = outputs[outputIdx][:,2]/stride

for output, correctOutput in zip(outputs,correctOutputs):
    print(np.array_equal(output,correctOutput))
```

The console output:

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: If you want to feed input to an internediate layer, maybe you can somehow create a new layer, connect it to the intermediate layer on the output side and keep the input free?